# How do I load a DOM element image div without downloading assets?

Tags: javascript, image, dom, html, viewport

Using the DOM I plan to load images into a page that are outside of the viewport of the browser.

THEN

only after the viewport scrolls over to a position in which the image div is located
does the image asset load.

Is there a simple answer to this that I just could not find?

Comment: http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload